# Keep temporary data until send response - Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm working on express server application and there are bunch of api endpoints that I configured. Almost all create and update requests, I need to store requested user's userId in order to keep log. I created a middleware function that verify user JWT access token and retrieve userId from access token payload. In my current situation, I add user info as `req.body.loggedUser` in req body. I think this is not a good thing to do. I do it like,

```
req.body.loggedUser = accessTokenPayload.user[0];
```

This works fine in every **POST** request. But I need to do it in right way. And also this method cannot use in **GET** requests. If nodejs can keep temporary variable until a request done its process I can keep log on **GET** requests also. So all I need to do is keep user info as **temporary data** until request process done. How I can do it.

Comment: Why dont you add user info straight in req?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to the `req` variable:

```
req.loggedUser = accessTokenPayload.user[0]
```

This works in GET requests as well